# Python " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute " suddenly appearing

Tags: python, attributes, getattr

so i have multiple 5 'Player' objects being created upon the start of my code, and about 24 different 'Skill' objects for each 'Player' Object,   im using this to loop through my code

```
first_run = True

while True:
    for i in range(len(player_name)):
    if first_run is True:
        player[i] = Player(player_name[i], player_url[i], player_thumbnail[i])
        print(player[i].name, "'s Object Created")

    data = requests.get(player_url[i])
    statusCheck(data.status_code, player_name[i])
    data_processed = re.split(', |\n', data.text)

    storeData(data_processed, player[i], first_run)

logging.info("Sleeping for 10 Seconds")
time.sleep(10)
first_run = False
```

basically on the first run through of this while loop, it will create 5 player objects that have predefined names that are stored in a list above. now when my code reaches `storeData(data_processed, player[i], first_run)` it reaches an issue in that function, an issue saying that an attribute created when the first player object is created doesnt exist, it was working absolutely perfectly, and then suddenly it stopped working, i didnt even change anything and suddenly its no longer working, here is the function "storeData" **( further below is the log error )**

```
def storeData(data_processed, player, first_run):
line_count = 0
for line in data_processed:
    if line != '':
        skill_data = line.split(',')
        if line_count < 24:
            player_skill = None
            player_skill = getattr(player, skills[line_count])
            player_skill.rank = skill_data[0]
            player_skill.level = skill_data[1]
            player_skill.xp = skill_data[2]
            line_count = line_count + 1
            if player_skill.last_level != player_skill.level and first_run is not True:
                logging.info(player.name, "Gained A Level in ", skills[line_count])
                pushLevelUp(discordUrl,skills[line_count-1], player, player_skill)
            player_skill.last_level = skill_data[1]

        elif line_count < 79:
            player_activity = getattr(player, activity[line_count - 24])
            player_activity.last_count = player_activity.count
            player_activity.rank = skill_data[0]
            player_activity.count = skill_data[1]
            line_count = line_count + 1
```

below is log error, i didnt change anything as i said, but it no longer finds player.skill.Overall ( using getattr )

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*hidden*", line 42, in <module>
    storeData(data_processed, player[i], first_run)
  File "*hidden*", line 142, in storeData
    player_skill = getattr(player, skills[line_count])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Overall'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

these are the lists in which i store the data for "skills"

```
skills = ['Overall', 'Attack', 'Defence', 'Strength', 'Hitpoints', 'Ranged', 'Prayer', 'Magic', 'Cooking',
      'Woodcutting', 'Fletching', 'Fishing', 'Firemaking', 'Crafting', 'Smithing', 'Mining', 'Herblore',
      'Agility', 'Thieving', 'Slayer', 'Farming', 'Runecrafting', 'Hunter', 'Construction']
```

**here is a quick rundown**

`player_skill = getattr(player, skills[line_count])` on first iteration should point directly to the player object passed into the `storeData` function, for this example il use "player", as the object name... the getattr on first iteration should point directly to `player.Overall`, which would allow me to call `player.Overall.level`, however it says it cannot find `player.Overall` when using `player_skill = getattr(player, skills[line_count])`

here are my .py files https://pastebin.com/q2VEFGfk ( this is file called 'runebotClassData' )   and this https://pastebin.com/h7BEckgR is ( runebotTest.py )

as i said, i changed nothing, the api seems to be returning the data exactly as normal, and that error is occuring, please help

Comment: If `first_run` is `False` then `player[i]` remains `None` which is handed over as parameter `player`  to `storeData` which then fails under some additional conditions.

Comment: oh sorry, i think i was testing at that point, the first definition of "first_run" should be true, but i set it to false whenever i want to test because it immediately prints embeded messages on discord if i do that

Comment: sorry, i meant the declaration, the declaration of first_run was meant to = True, but even if it was set to True the problem still occurs

Comment: You could check if "player" is None at beginning of "storeData" and raise a "ValueError" if so. This would at least show the error earlier and more reliably so that its cause can be found.

Comment: I will do some testing today, however if i recall it suddenly started working last night, and if so it might be an issue with the api , but im pretty sure the data was being sourced as normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wow i overlooked that completely, i was blinded by the error pointing to where player[i] was being called, not where it was defined, and it wasnt defined if my testing mode was on ( first_run = False ) i should have paid more attention to the declaration